# Sage pay Form Protocol 3.00 Simulator

Tags: forms, simulator, opayo

Does Sagepay Simulator supports protocol 3.00? I tried but it gives me "The VPSProtocol field you supplied contains invalid data. It should contain the value 2.23".

Answer (score 5):

Short answer. No it doesn't....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: In what way does that not answer the question? 

The simulator hasn't been updated to protocol 3.00!

Comment: @SonerGönül Not sure what answer you read but this definitely answers the question

Comment: Thanks! This avoids having to try and get simulator account access then.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and have contact SagePay asking more details on how to proceed for testing version 3.00 using Simulator and they answered me back:

> "Good Afternoon Ryan,
>
> Thanks for your email. Unfortunately the simulator is no longer
>   supported with any protocol. Our recommendation is to use the Test
>   environment to test v3.00."